# How to Open New Activity when Recycler Items Are Clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

When I click item of RecyclerView and I want to be able to open another activity. How can I do this?

This code is my recycler adapter onBindViewHolder code.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) 
  {
    holder.setItemclickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                if(isLongClick){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Long Click"+ dataset.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(context,"short Click"+ dataset.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }`enter code here`
        });

        Groups tiklanilan=dataset.get(position);

        holder.groupnametext.setText(tiklanilan.getGroupname());

        //holder.groupimage.setImageResource(tiklanilan.getImageURL());


    }
```

Comment: And what is behavior with above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use setItemClickListener but instead in your onBindViewHolder add a clickListener on your root view and call the method startActivity in that clickListener.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AccountListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getContext().startActivity(yourIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```